# What's a good single-word term that means "a user who's signed in to your website"?

Tags: usability, users, roles

I'm trying to devise the standard nomenclature for our application, and I wanted to use a term that can be used across all our documentation and artifacts (i.e. user flows, scenario maps, etc.)

A **Member** is someone who's registered to your service, but not necessarily logged into the application/site.

A **Guest** is someone who uses your services without being registered or logged in.

**User** is too broad of a term, in my opinion. A user can be anyone, whether he or she is a member or guest. Basically, anyone who uses the application.

**Authenticated User** or **Authenticated Member** is closest to what I'm searching for, but I'm still holding out for a shorter term.

Comment: What's the application name? And what is it used for?

Comment: In case if your application name is Google, you can use Welcome Googler - similar to welcome user

Comment: @Diego IMO that would still be to similar to guest. I.e. you could still Google while logged in or not so it doesn't necessarily specify the users state.

Comment: In internal communication you could use "Authenticated User", but that's usually too technical to be used when communicating with said user.

Comment: This doesn't seem to really be a UX issue, but instead a development one.  Maybe this question should be moved to programmers.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @Jules I don't see how this is a development issue? This is about how users should be called. It's a marketing/UX issue at least.

Comment: IMHO, your current choices are the most common and less ambiguous of all. There's a reason why *guest* and *member* have been used since the dawn of Internet. Do not re-invent the wheel, it was already invented and it works

Comment: You can use the term "visitor".

Comment: @PierreArlaud - I may be misunderstanding the question, but as I read it, it asks how those users should be called *by the development team and designers* and not specifically in user-facing situations.

Comment: Given that you need a single word for someone who's logged in, it seems pretty obvious that "Loggedinosaur" is the most appropriate term.

Comment: I'm confused on those 2 points too: 1) Is this a term used for internal design & development, or in text for customers too? 2) Do you mean users who are currently logged in at the moment, or users who have ever logged in & validated?

Comment: How about "logged in user"? It's not one word, but you can't mistake the meaning

Comment: @gandalf3 you can just go all German on it and stick the words together loggedinuser, bingo one word

Comment: Point of clarification: your question title asks for "a word that describes a user who is signed in".  That word is "authenticated".  I think your question is wrongly worded, resulting in a lot of unsuitable answers.  You meant to ask for a word that _means_ "a user who is signed in" - a nound, not a word that _describes_ a user who is signed in - an adjective.

Comment: Why are you "holding out for a shorter term" - I'm not sure the benefit of intentionally obfuscating things for the sake of brevity.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

**When describing website functionality, you can usually use "Member" to imply a logged-in user.**

While someone could technically be a member but not logged in, this is unlikely to be relevant to your discussions.  While not logged in, they are effectively seeing the "guest" view of the site.

I think this is clear:

> On the home page, a member will have a feed of their recent activity, while a guest will see a suggestion to sign up in the same space.
>
> A member has a button to view and edit their account details in the top navigation.

etc.

I don't think you need anything else.  "Logged in" is implied by the context of the discussion.

One place where this terminology might not apply is discussion of the log in process itself.  But again, I think this will be clear from context.  If there is an occasional time where it's not clear, you can always describe it with more words.

Comment: well explained :) . I think the OP is an archetypical *Occam's Razor* question, where the solution to the problem is the simplest one, like in this case

Comment: "Logged in" is implied by the context of the simple example you suggest, but consider for instance an online game where a player may want to pick other players who are currently online in order to play together.,, in that situation, you would need a term for distinguishing between the two.

Comment: This is insightful. I was looking for a term that I can generally use when designing user flows etc. A "member" can be someone who is registered with the service, but NOT necessarily logged into the site. "Authenticated member" might be close to what I need, but I'm still brainstorming for a single-word term.

Comment: @Ellesa. Perhaps you are focusing too much on terminology.  Terms exist to facilitate clear description, but I'm not sure you need an additional term in order to describe functionality clearly.  I don't think a single succinct term exists to describe what you want, and if you choose something artificial that doesn't quite fit, it may hinder rather than help clarity.

Comment: @Jules, why?  That would just be "user" or "online user."  Also, English has modifiers for a reason; you *don't need* a noun for every possible combination of modifiers and nouns.

Comment: I've been contemplating this for a while - I don't know why I never bothered to ask this question here!   I agree with @Ellesa, "member" should just refer to someone who has *registered*.  Perhaps we need a new word.  How about "auser", a portmanteau pronounced "ow-zer"?

Comment: I think it depends on how important the attribute "logged in" is in the context of question.    If the question is "what is a term for a user who is a member and is currently signed in, as opposed to one who is not signed in yet", then clearly "member" is not the right term!

Answer (score 19):

**Authenticated**

For example: Windows user groups have defined names one of which is Authenticated.

> The Authenticated Users identity Any user accessing the system through
>   a logon process has the Authenticated Users identity. This identity
>   allows access to shared resources within the domain, such as files in
>   a shared folder that should be accessible to all the workers in the
>   organization.

See this answer on security.stackexchange for an explanation of the different user group terms.
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38830/windows-groups-and-permissions-authenticated-users-group-meaning

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it is an adjective, not a noun, so you can't really use it as a single word to describe the authenticated users -- you have to use two words, like I just did.

Comment: Authenticated in my opinion is a member that has completed a 2 step registry process. 1) Signed in 2) Clicked or confirmed a message sent to the email. But this confirmation is not always required.

Comment: @Rafael: In a security context, to "authenticate" is to prove that you are who you claim to be.  You authenticate every time you provide a password, OAuth token, or any other credentials that establish your identity.  This is distinct from "authorization," which is concerned with whether your account has access to a particular resource.

Comment: "Authenticatee"? :/

Answer (score 8):

**Edit: Actually "Active" might be the best**. You wouldn't really refer to "active" guests, but you do have "active" members. This is what Slack uses and Google also uses 'activity' to refer to log of signing in and out of Google accounts.

**Original answer:**

Effectively you're looking for an adjective for your Members.

I'd say "Online" is best.

It's the term used by Skype uses to indicate that someone is logged in and active at the moment.

Another possibility is "Active", but that doesn't quite suggest that they are active 'now'.

Comment: While I like this answer and upvoted it, I think this terminology applies only for apps with peers activity (see how you mention only that kind of apps). We don't have much info, but if this is just a static site, a member could be *active* or totally *inactive* (see this site as example). Also, *Online* might ring alarm bells since many people will want to keep their status unknown. This being said, it's a good answer

Comment: @Devin I wasn't thinking that 'online' would be displayed publicly, just that the OP was asking for a way to describe these users in internal documentation. I agree neither of these are perfect, it's a challenging question :) Possibly more suited to English.SE

Answer (score 4):

There is no commonly used single-word term for this, so I would suggest avoiding inventing one or picking an obscure one, as this is only likely to confuse anyone who isn't familiar with your terminology (e.g. new members of your team, third parties you subcontract to, etc).  "Authenticated user" is the usual term for this, so I'd suggest using it.

Comment: In 20+ years I have always seen the words *member* or *registered user* commonly used everywhere, both in technical teams, clients, end-users and so on. I've never seen this causing any friction or complication at all. However, I can define scenarios where your suggestion *"Authenticated user"* causes a lot of friction and requires additional information. For example... where is the user authenticated? Front end? Back end? Is the user someone from the dev team or one of the end users? I think it's easy to see something like *member* is very easy to understand with minimal ambiguity (if any)

Comment: @Devin - Neither "member" nor "registered user" fits the question, though, because the asker is asking about *users who are currently logged in*, which is only a subset of the users who are members or are registered.  If there is an issue with "authenticated" then "online" or "logged-in" are both viable alternatives, depending on the context.

Comment: Now I see: I think everybody is getting another interpretation of signed (as someone that has signed to your site) while you're interpreting someone that is signed at a given time (as in *currently using it*). Guess the Op will need to clarify this, because if the latter is correct, then this could probably be the correct answer

Comment: You actually confuse more saying "Authenticated user" rather than just "Logged in", "Online"...

Comment: @Devin  A member is a member whether or not they are currently signed in...

Answer (score 3):

In the past we've used *live user* to mean a user who is currently signed in. (As opposed to an *active user*: somebody who has signed in recently, but isn't necessarily signed in right now.)

Answer (score 2):

Since these terms are for your internal documentation, it's most important to be clear and unambiguous. And I don't think a single word will be good enough. I usually use "authorized user" or "signed-in user" and "anonymous user" for that reason.

Answer (score 1):

"Onymous" is the antonym of anonymous, so I guess that's an (obscure) option.

I would say that "member" is the name of a role of a user, and not a type of user.

"Subject" is also a candidate, as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989063/what-is-the-meaning-of-subject-vs-user-vs-principal-in-a-security-context

Comment: Onymous is an adjective, so it is no better than "Authenticated", and does not offer a single word solution.

Comment: Nope, Anonymous is a proper noun! https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_(group) . Therefore, so is onymous

Comment: Onymous is only a proper noun if you are using it to refer to an established... some_thing_.  In it's meaning that you quoted, as the antonym of anonymous, it is an adjective, and you would have to say "onymous user".   You can't say "there is one onymous user on my site".

Comment: Actually, to be fair, one could read the title of this question as specifically asking for an adjective: a "term to describe a user" - an onymous user.   However, the body of the question makes it clear it it is looking for a noun, because the examples given of "the right kind of word" are nouns, and "authenticated user" (IE an adjective describing the user) is ruled out.

Comment: I'll actually try that for my new project

Answer (score 0):

You could, with proper explanation call an user who is logged in an "inlogee"

(I'm not an native english speaker ;-) )

Comment: This is a funny suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

## Online

This means "logged in member". E.g. **member1** is **online**.

It's better to use "online"/"offline" rather than just "member". "Member" can be a position e.g.

```
[pic:mbr_1]
mbr_1
** ONLINE **
MEMBER
```

`[pic:]` refers to the avatar. Position examples are "Member", "Admin", "Banned until ", "Banned permanently"...

Comment: Online is an adjective, so it is no better than authenticated.  In fact, it is worse, because I can be online without authenticating (arguably).   It does not offer a single word solution.

Comment: @GreenAsJade I don't prefer nouns. Also, if you're not authenticated, you are a guest, not your account.

Answer (score 0):

## Actives

You could use the slang `actives` to describe users that are currently active in your application.

This draws on the similar practice in the military of asking how many hostiles / friendlies are in an area.

Comment: A member can be active on your site without being logged in.

Comment: @GreenAsJade In that case those members who are *active* but aren't signed in wouldn't count toward the actives count. Maybe that muddies the intention of calling them actives but that's sort of the role of slang terms in english.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong. But what you really care about is distinguishing someone who is not a logged in user from those who are. Because once you're logged in, all of those other roles apply. The distinction is "visitor" a "visitor" is a non-logged in user. Everyone else is well "Authenticated"

Answer (score 0):

What about the term "active user"? In forums we have many panels that list the "active" users who are always users that are currently "online" or "logged-in".

Best of luck!

Comment: Another shorter term would be "live" credit to "scottishwildcat" for this one!

Answer (score -1):

We might need more context to help you answer your question. You might be challenged to find a single word, so I can give you two words - Account holder, or User Account.

Comment: "Account holder" doesn't really tell you anything more than "User" would about their current status or level of activity. It literally just means they have an account, not that they're logged in to their account or using it.

Answer (score -1):

It's difficulf because you may have end users who use the system in very different ways including users who manage other users. I'd suggest something like either *Current* or *Actor*

Answer (score -1):

In retail sites, signed in users are sometomes called as hot customers and guest users as cold customers.

Comment: Does "cold customer" imply that the person can be ignored or dropped from the active list? When, in reality, those might be the visitors you most focus on.

Comment: cold means user is not signed in. Its more like a state of user, which has not signed in (yet).